# Record how many times a while loop runs? - python

Tags: python, loops

Imagine this:

*You have a while loop*

*You want to know how many times it ran*

*What should you do???*

Now I hear you say, *what is the context?*

**Context:**
I am writing this program in Python which thinks of a number between 1 and 100, and you are to guess it. The guessing takes part in a while loop (please have a look at the code below) but I need to know how many guesses are made.

So, this is what I need:

```
print("It took you " + number_of_guesses + " guesses to get this correct.")
```

This is the complete code at Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d33c9ace3f67642ac09

**Please remember: I am using Python 3x**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
count = 0

while x != y::
   count +=1 # variable will increment every loop iteration
   # your code


print count
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'll have a look at the others

Answer (score 5):

just for fun , your whole program in 4 (somewhat readable) lines of code

```
sentinel = random.randint(1,10)
def check_guess(guess):
    print ("Hint:(too small)" if guess < sentinel else "Hint:(too big)")
    return True

total_guesses = sum(1 for guess in iter(lambda:int(input("Can you guess it?: ")), sentinel) if check_guess(guess)) + 1
```

Comment: Or to save memory `sum(1 for _ in iter(...))` instead of `len(list(iter(...)))`.

Comment: @SteveJessop -- While you're right ... if the data is actually coming from `input`, I doubt that the user is going to type enough numbers to make a dent on the system's total memory usage...

Comment: @mgilson: of course, it's just that if you're going to use generators at all, then generally you want to know how to avoid intermediate lists. Whether you actually *need* to avoid it in this case is irrelevant to the fun! It's really just a question of how quickly you prefer `yes 0 | ./guessing_game.py` to error out.

Comment: heh this is one of those if you have a hammer everything looks like a nail answers :P I just really like that iter trick

Answer (score 4):

One option is to convert

```
while loop_test:
    whatever()
```

to

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count():
    if not loop_test:
        break
    whatever()
```

If it's a `while True`, this simplifies to

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count():
    whatever()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
counter = 0
while True:
   counter += 1
   # get input
   # process input
   # if done: break
```

Answer (score 0):

## Very very simple way to make Counter add 1 everytime a condition is true or false, you use it which ever way you like or need. Also, I'm a rookie.

counter = 0

while x != y:

```
if somethingHere == somethingThere:
    counter = counter + 1 
    #your code here
elif somethingHere > somethingThere:
    counter = counter + 1
    #your code here
else
    counter = counter + 1
    #your code here
```

print(counter)